# PayPal Pro (Direct) Credit Cart expiration date verification in Magento

Tags: magento, paypal, credit-card

I have an installation of Magento shop on my development server and as a payment gateway we are using PayPal Pro (PayPal Direct) which is able to accept users' credit cards.

It was fine in sandbox mode, but after switching into 'live' mode and testing with $0.01 transactions, it came out that PayPal seem to accept CCs without checking expiration date, but CC number and CVV are checked.

So here are the questions:

1. How insecure is to leave CC processing to work without expire date check?
2. How to get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of these credit card numbers to do testing with PayPal as given [here on the PayPal site](http://www.paypal.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm):

> While testing, use only the credit card numbers listed here. Other numbers produce an error.
>
> Expiration Date must be a valid date in the future (use the **mmyy** format).
>
> #### Test Credit Card Account Numbers
>
> ```
> +----------------------------+------------------------------------------+
> | Credit Card Type           | Credit Card Number                       |
> +----------------------------+------------------------------------------+
> | American Express           | 378282246310005                          |
> | American Express           | 371449635398431                          |
> | American Express Corporate | 378734493671000                          |
> | Australian BankCard        | 5610591081018250                         |
> | Diners Club                | 30569309025904                           |
> | Diners Club                | 38520000023237                           |
> | Discover                   | 6011111111111117                         |
> | Discover                   | 6011000990139424                         |
> | JCB                        | 3530111333300000                         |
> | JCB                        | 3566002020360505                         |
> | MasterCard                 | 5555555555554444                         |
> | MasterCard                 | 5105105105105100                         |
> | Visa                       | 4111111111111111                         |
> | Visa                       | 4012888888881881                         |
> | Visa                       | 4222222222222                            |
> |                            | Note : Even though this number has a     |
> |                            | different character count than the other |
> |                            | test numbers, it is the correct and      |
> |                            | functional number.                       |
> +----------------------------+------------------------------------------+
> | Processor-specific Cards   |                                          |
> +----------------------------+------------------------------------------+
> | Dankort (PBS)              | 76009244561                              |
> | Dankort (PBS)              | 5019717010103742                         |
> | Switch/Solo (Paymentech)   | 6331101999990016                         |
> +----------------------------+------------------------------------------+
> ```

Comment: thanks, vipul, but what about live payments and expiration date?

Comment: expiration date should be in the future always